# Batch File Loop - Skip file, if file name contains string

Tags: string, batch-file, comparison, filenames

I am trying to do essentially the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890205/batch-file-loop-skip-file-if-name-contains), i.e. I want to loop through files in a directory, but exclude files that have in their name a certain string (in my case ".new.". However, the problem is that I am using

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
```

because I want the batch also to work with file names that contain exclamation marks. I have thus tried to make the solution work using directly the loop variable %%x instead of a new variable, but that does not appear to work:

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%x in (*.mkv *.mp4) do (
  If "%%x" == "%%x:.new." (
    Echo Skipped "%%x"
  ) Else (
    Echo Processing "%%x"
  )
)
```

String matching doesn't work, i.e. I get

```
Processing "file.mkv"    
Processing "file.new.mkv"
```

Any hint for how I could get this to work would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Batch string-manipulation commands can't be applied directly to `metavariables` like `%%x`.

```
echo %%x|findstr /i /L ".new.">nul
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo process %%x
) else (
 echo skip %%x
)
```

should work for you, finding the string `.new.` `/l` literally, `/i` case-insensitive. set `errorlevel` to `0` if found, non-0 otherwise.